# Soundconverter is not working after upgrading to ubuntu 15.10

Tags: python, 15.10

Since I upgrade to ubuntu 15.10, soundconverter is not launching anymore.

Here's the output when I try to launch it, without any parameters

```
$ soundconverter 
SoundConverter 2.1.5
  using Gstreamer version: 0.10.36
  using 4 thread(s)
  using gio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/soundconverter", line 189, in <module>
gui_main(NAME, VERSION, GLADEFILE, files)
  File "/usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/ui.py", line 1512, in gui_main
win = SoundConverterWindow(builder)
  File "/usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/ui.py", line 1177, in __init__
self.prefs = PreferencesDialog(builder, self.widget)
  File "/usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/ui.py", line 447, in __init__
self.set_widget_initial_values(builder)
  File "/usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/ui.py", line 479, in set_widget_initial_values
uri = filename_to_uri(self.get_string('selected-folder'))
  File "/usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/fileoperations.py", line 150, in filename_to_uri
filename = str(gnomevfs.URI(filename))
TypeError: could not parse URI
```

And the version of soundconverter installed

```
$ apt-cache policy soundconverter
soundconverter:
  Installé : 2.1.5-1
  Candidat : 2.1.5-1
 Table de version :
 *** 2.1.5-1 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The error output of strace -e open /usr/bin/soundconverter can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13582686/

Result of the path as seen from python :

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.path.expanduser('~'))
/home/roms
```

It's my home directory as you guessed, since i use roms as user name.

Comment: Does this happen as soon as the program is opened or do you interact with it at all first?

Comment: Please launch `python` from a terminal window. Run `import os` and then `print(os.path.expanduser('~'))`. Please edit your question to include what it prints.

Comment: @Seth : It crashes as soon as i try to open it, i don't even get the GUI.

Comment: Run `sudo nano /usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/fileoperations.py`. Scroll down to line 143 and add `print(filename)` at line 150. It should look like this when you're done: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13601022/. Run soundconverter again. It won't fix anything but will show several more lines of output. Upload the output to paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link. Also, what is the output of `sed -n '398p' /usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/ui.py`?

Comment: @Seth I edited fileoperations.py as you suggested. It said something about an indentation problem. I don't know python but i try to remove a tab and it seems to work. Here are the different outputs : http://paste.ubuntu.com/13606041/ the first says something about a file permission. Strangely that file was root:root so i reowned it and try to launch soundconverter again, that the second output. And i added the result of the sed command

Comment: yes, Python uses indentation instead of curly braces to denotate scope. Assuming you corrected the print line to match the indentation of the lines below it (just like in my example) this is turning out to be a very strange problem. What does `uri = filename_to_uri(self.get_string('selected-folder'))` return?

Comment: Where should i enter this line ?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a clipboard error on my part. This is what I meant: `sed -n '479p' /usr/share/soundconverter/python/soundconverter/ui.py` (a regular terminal command). If you have some time this might be easier to troubleshoot in [chat]. Ping me in the general room if you have some time and hopefully we can work this out there (I *should* be available most of the day).

Comment: The result is indeed : uri = filename_to_uri(self.get_string('selected-folder')) . It looks like we have a 9 hours shift between us, explaining why we are never here at the same time...

Comment: I'm in the chat room right now, just got your message :)